# Wildfly does not update MBean session attributes (JMX)

Tags: wildfly, jmx, mbeans, wildfly-22

I am accessing WildFly (22) via JMX to access one of its MBeans. It is the session information of an web application. This is generally working however I can only see one attribute changing over time which is the `activeSessions` attribute. All other attributes like `expiredSessions`, `highestSessionCount`, `maxActiveSessions`, `rejectedSessions`, `sessionsCreated` etc always remain **0**.

Does anybody know the reason for this? Is some special activation for those values necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. In order to gather statistics about HTTP sessions, you need to enable statistics on undertow subsystem. One possibility is to use the CLI as follows:

```
/subsystem=undertow:write-attribute(name=statistics-enabled,value=true)
```

or directly in the standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:XX.0" default-server="default-server"  statistics-enabled="true">
```